# Automatically remove generator object from memory at StopIteration (Python)

Tags: python, memory-management, generator

I noticed once a generator is exhausted, the object remains in memory. **How can I make the generator object automatically remove itself from memory once it is exhausted?**

Comment: If you've only got one reference to it, just `del generator`.

Comment: @agf: Please post your answer as an answer so we can upvote it properly.

Comment: "I noticed once a generator is exhausted, the object remains in memory".  How did you notice this?  Please provide code.  It could be that you've created your own problem by creating yet another reference to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making a wrapper generator that makes sure it doesn't have a reference to the inner generator once it finishes. The following might even do it (completely untested):

```
def strange(gen):
    for thing in gen:
        yield thing
```

Once `gen` raises `StopIteration` the `strange` generator will exit the for loop and then return `None`, which will again raise `StopIteration`. If `gen` was the last reference to the generator, it should/might be available to be garbage collected before whatever code is iterating over `strange(gen)` gets control back. On CPython that would mean it is freed.

Note that that won't help if you do something like the following:

```
g = some_generator()
for x in strange(g):
    do_something()
```

Because `g` itself is a reference to the inner generator. You'd have to be using it more like this:

```
for x in strange(some_generator()):
    do_something()
```

But really, the simplest method is to do what you do with any other object when you don't want it to hang around in memory: make sure you're not holding on to a reference to it. If the variable referencing it was in a long lived scope, you can explicitly `del` it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an operation supported by Python.